# Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{|x|}{x}$ does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits, absolute-value

I thought absolute values were positive? Why is the there a negative $x$ in example $7$ in the attached picture. Can someone explain? [image]

Comment: Because of the ambiguity of $x\to 0$: It approaches $0$ in two ways, from the left side and from the right side.

Answer (score 3):

If you remember from the definition of the absolute value, $|x| = x$ if $x \geq 0$, and $|x| = -x$ if $x < 0$ (because if $x$ is less than zero, we take it to be negative, which makes it positive, for example, if $x = -3$, then $|x| = -(-3) = 3$, which is what we want).

So from the right side, we're taking $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{|x|}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} 1 = 1$$ and from the right side, we're taking $$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{|x|}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^-} -\frac{x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^-}  -1 = -1$$ And remember that we can only say the limit exists if it approaches the same value from both sides.

Comment: You mean from the left side? Maybe you could explain this to me as if I was a 5 year old I would understand it better. Now if x>0 it is x and if x<0 it is -x which turns it positive. I understand that. Is the 0 positive in the denominator and...lets say -0.00999 in the numerator?

Comment: First, there's no need to consider the case where $x = 0$ (because this can't happen, because $x$ is in the denominator). Fortunately, that doesn't matter, because in limits, we don't care what actually happens *at* the point we're approaching. We just care about what happens *near* it. So as we're approaching from the right side, we know $x$ is positive, and since $x > 0$, then $|x| = x$ by definition. So for any $x > 0$, we have that $|x|/x = 1$. However, looking at the left side, we have that $x < 0$, so $|x| = -x$, so $|x|/x| = (-x)/x = -1$.

Comment: Notice that from the left side, the numerator is positive (because it's an absolute value), but the denominator is negative (because $x$ is less than $0$). So for every $x < 0$, this term is equal to $-1$. So as you get closer and closer to $0$ from the left side, you're still approaching $-1$. But on the right side, you're approaching $+1$. Hence, the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay. So it not the absolute value that is negative it is the theoretical idea that the denominator, although not zero, is negative since it is coming from the left side of zero (the negative side) causing the entire quotient to be negative?

Comment: What's causing it to be negative is that the absolute value wants to always be positive, but the denomenator will be negative whenever $x$ is negative. What causes the quotient to become negative is that difference in sign--the numerator wants to stay positive, but the denominator is negative because $x < 0$. Notice that if instead we wanted $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x}$$ then we would have no problem, because the top and bottom always have the same sign, so the limit is always $1$.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to think of the absolute value of a number as the distance of a number from zero on the number line. For instance, the absolute value of $7$ and $-7$ is $7$. Why? because the distance of $7$ and $-7$ from $0$ are both $7$.

To answer your question as to why $x$ is negative as it approaches $0$ from the left side, know that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the absolute value of $x$ denoted $|x|$ is defined by

$$|x| = \begin{cases}-x &\text{if $x<0,$} \\ 0 &\text{if $x=0,$} \\x &\text{if $x>0.$} \\\end{cases}$$

Since $x$ is approaching from the left side, we must have that $x<0$. By definition of absolute value, we use $-x$.

Your confusion with the absolute value being positive all the time lies in thinking about the distance of numbers $x$ from $0$. For $x<0$, the $\textbf{distance}$ of $x$ from $0$ must of course be positive, but by definition, the $\textbf{sign}$of $x$ is negative for $x<0$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**:Note that $x \to 0^{-}$ means that $x \to 0$, *and* $x < 0$, thus $|x| = -x$.

Comment: x=0 and is placed in the denominator and the numerator, right? So, if o is placed in the || it turns positive. Or do I misunderstand this concept?

Comment: Be advised that there is a low quality flag on your answer. It received a mixed response from fellow users from the Low Quality review Queue. I don't know what to read into that? May be some of your peers think that a high rep user such as yourself should post this hint as a comment? May be something else? I don't think that any moderator action is warranted. This is just FYI.

Comment: Also for F.Y.I, i rather have a low quality answer since this is for the OP than have low quality person. I don't really care about what they flag since I don't serve any body here. I am here to have fun and to help out some students who need help.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value is never negative -- you're confusing the minus sign with it being negative. Since $x<0$, we have that $|x| = -x > 0$. Hence we get when approaching from the left side $|x|/x = -x/x = -1$.

For example when $x = -0.01$, then $|x| = -(-0.01) = 0.01$ and $|x|/x = 0.01/(-0.01) = -1.$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\varepsilon=1/2$; if the limit exists and equals $l$, you could find $\delta>0$ such that, for $0<|x|<\delta$,
$$
\left|\frac{|x|}{x}-l\right|<\frac{1}{2}
$$
However, for $x=\delta/2$, we have
$$
\frac{|\delta/2|}{\delta/2}=1
$$
so we must have $|1-l|<1/2$, that is $-1/2<l-1<1/2$ or
$$
\frac{1}{2}<l<\frac{3}{2}.
$$
But, for $x=-\delta/2$, we have
$$
\frac{|-\delta/2|}{-\delta/2}=-1
$$
so we must have $|-1-l|<1/2$, that is $-1/2<l+1<1/2$ or
$$
-\frac{3}{2}<l<-\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Since we can't have both $l>1/2$ and $l<-1/2$, we conclude that $l$ doesn't exist.